# ActionMailer Emails Failing-Cancel Current Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmail, actionmailer

My app is attempting to send email notifications using ActionMailer, but all emails are failing.

Here is the error: "Too many login attempts, please try again later. om8sm998783qeb.4 - gsmtp"

I want to kill all of the emails that are trying to be sent, does anyone know a way to do this?

The email that is being used is a gmail, my app is hosted on Heroku. I know I have emails configured properly, it isn't something in my code 100%.

Comment: If you are using Heroku, I would recommend using SendGrid. It it very easy to set up and it works flawlessly. And, unless you are sending a couple thousand emails a month, it's all free.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use SendGrid or a similar email forwarding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to temporarily stop email deliveries in your app, you can set the following action mailer configuration to false.

```
# specifies whether mail will actually be delivered and is true by default. 
# It can be convenient to set it to false for testing.
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

If you want to instead queue them up, you could use something like DelayedJob (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to queue them into the database. By default, it will retry failed deliveries on a progressive back-off delay.